# mobx - Out of bounds read: 0

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am using Mobx `6.1.8` with React in my project.

I have a store that has the following observable:

```
export class Store {
  organizations: Array<IOrganization> = [];

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      organizations: observable,
      setOrganizations: action,
    });
  }


  setOrganizations = (organizations: IOrganization[]) => {
    this.organizations = organizations;
  };

}
```

When I used it in another class, I get the following error:

```
[mobx] Out of bounds read: 0
```

The `slice()` doesn't work for me. Can you please help me?

Comment: What line of code is triggering the error, can you share it?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to reference `organizations[0]` somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is triggerd when you are trying to access an index > Array.length, you can add `debugger` here to find out which line is calling this.

```
get_(index: number): any | undefined {
    if (this.legacyMode_ && index >= this.values_.length) {
        console.warn(
            __DEV__
                ? `[mobx.array] Attempt to read an array index (${index}) that is out of bounds (${this.values_.length}). Please check length first. Out of bound indices will not be tracked by MobX`
                : `[mobx] Out of bounds read: ${index}`
        )
        return undefined
    }
    this.atom_.reportObserved()
    return this.dehanceValue_(this.values_[index])
}
```

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/7cdc7ecd6947a6da10f10d2e4a1305297b816007/packages/mobx/src/types/observablearray.ts#L347